# Unable to use default value for GUID in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm converting an 8-year old ASP.NET application to MVC5, but encountering an issue dealing with the existing database.

Using .NET 4.6, EF 6.1.3 (Database First) and MVC5, extracted the database into my project.
My issue, the SiteKey should be generated from the DB, but I can't figure out how to do this properly. I'm unable to make changes to the Context, since this is auto-generated from the EF extraction utility.

What do I provide DEFAULT for the Controller, to update the database?
It seems I must generate on the client-side, which may break my application?
Secondarily, can I use this same method for my timestamp column RowVersion?

Table in SQL

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Site](
    [SiteID] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [SiteKey] [uniqueidentifier] DEFAULT(newid()) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SiteURL] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [SiteStateID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()),
    [RenewalDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE()),
    [RenewalPlanID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_Site_SiteKey] UNIQUE (SiteKey)
    )
```

Create Method in the SitesController

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = 
    "SiteID,SiteKey,CompanyID,SiteURL,SiteStateID,CreateDate,
    RenewalDate,RenewalPlanID,RowVersion")] Site site)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Sites.Add(site);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName", site.CompanyID);
        ViewBag.RenewalPlanID = new SelectList(db.RenewalPlans, "RenewalPlanID", "Code", site.RenewalPlanID);
        ViewBag.SiteStateID = new SelectList(db.SiteStates, "SiteStateID", "SiteState1", site.SiteStateID);
        return View(site);
    }
```

Auto-generated Site Class

```
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid SiteKey { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string SiteURL { get; set; }
    public byte SiteStateID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime RenewalDate { get; set; }
    public int RenewalPlanID { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your EDMX diagram, select the `SiteKey` property and open the properties window. Ensure that **StoreGeneratedPattern** is set to **identity**.

Comment: That was the answer.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
[SiteKey] [uniqueidentifier] DEFAULT(newid()) NOT NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
```

The values of these two columns are generated automatically when you insert new data in the table, so you shouldn't care to modify the values manually. Actually, the value of `SiteKey` is generated because of `DEFAULT(newid())`, which means that every time you omit inserting a value for `SiteKey`, a new and unique value will be created for you. Here you can find more details: [uniqueidentifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx) and [timestamp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx).

If you wanto to manually insert the values, you should be able to do something like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    site.SiteKey = System.Guid.NewGuid();

    db.Sites.Add(site);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I may not have been clear, I want the database to handle this.  Currently, the value being generated for the SiteKey is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 in the controller, rather then an internally generated value such as: AA265585-5925-4C66-894E-B423F418F7A4.

Thanks